# RXSwift - How to recall an api

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

i created an observable for an api call and bind to a tableview. Now i am unclear ***how to call the same api once again? so as to do a refresh*** - say on an button click?. The following is my sample code.

Please let me know your thoughts it will be helpfull

```
 var items : Observable<[String]>? 
   func viewDidLoad(){

            items = fetchAllAnswers()
          items.bindTo(....).addDisposableTo(bag)
    }
   func fetchAllAnswers() -> Observable<[String]>{
   let api = Observable.create { (obsever: AnyObserver<[String]>) -> Disposable in
        let answers = API.allAnswers()
                     obsever.onNext(answers)
                     obsever.onCompleted()
                    return AnonymousDisposable{
                        print("api dispose called")
                    }
                }
                return api

            }

    func onClickRefresh()
   {
   // how to call api here again?


   //  let items = fetchAllAnswers() 
    // items.bindTo(....).addDisposableTo(bag)

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simple. You may to use Variable for update your items:

```
let items =  Variable([String]())
```

Next you must to bind items with your UITableView:

```
items.asObservable.bindTo(....).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Next you may to update your items in subscriber:

```
fetchAllAnswers()
.subscribeNext { stringArray in 
    items.value = stringArray
}
.addDisposableTo(bag)
```

If you want to update your table by button click, you may to do next:

```
yourButton.rx_tap
.flatMap { void -> Observable<[String]> in
    return fetchAllAnswers()
}
.subscribeNext { stringArray in 
    items.value = stringArray
}
.addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Comment: I have already bind it to a tableview to populate using .bindTo(). Does it means that i have to bind it again? please refer the code. i just want to call the api again hoping the data will repopulate in tableview

Comment: I updated my answer. In your case i prefer to use Variable, can you try to use it?

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: Any progress? If my answer helped you, mark it as right please.

Comment: Thanks! Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  button.rx_tap.startWith().flatMap { _ in
    fetchAllAnswers()
  }.bindTo(...).addDisposableTo(bag)
}
```

`flatMap` will transform taps to the result of the observable the closure returns, here a `String` array.

`startWith()` will force `rx_tap` to emit a first value at subscription time, so that the first refresh behavior is kept.